Middle School Narrative Math Textbook
A couple decades ago, I remember teaching myself trig and calculus from some textbooks that I got from the library. They were set in a fantasy kingdom and concepts were introduced to solve various problems (e. g., trig was used to calculate the height of trees to pick one they needed to cut down). Does anyone know what this series is or if there are any other similar narratively driven textbooks?

Probably not this one though corresponding partly to your description.

@hbacovci: Is it the series like Calculus: The Easy Way by Douglas Downing that uses the kingdom of Carmorra as an aid? There is also Trigonometry the Easy Way.

Regarding your title, trigonometry and calculus is middle school?? When I was in school it wasn't until high school that we could even take beginning algebra, although now beginning algebra is fairly common for stronger middle school students (U.S. perspective).

Trigonometry the easy way looks like it. Thank you very much!

Regarding my comment about "middle school", see this recent news story.
